# isupper and islower for wstring

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, mfc

I have a std::wstring and I want to find which character are upper 
case and which ones are lowercase. the std::isupper and islower seems 
to work on ASCII characters only but I want to be able to find out all 
kinds of uppercase and lowercase characters

e.g. á is an "Latin small letter a with acute" 
and  Á is an "Latin capital letter A with acute" 
similarly ä and Ä are lower and upper case german letters.

Is there any function (mfc, boost or in any other library) which I can 
use to find out if a character is lower or upper case (irrespective of the locale)?

Thanks in advance

Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most implementations are going to provide iswXxx functions, i.e. `iswupper` and `iswlower`. The big problem is that the encoding used in wide character strings is undefined and therefore which values are determined as upper and lower case are really up to the target platform. (Note that the iswXxx functions are not in the standard)

EDIT: And Bill is an idiot! The template declared in `<locale>` for `std::isupper` accepts both `char`s and `wchar_t`s. (But it requires a locale object)

Comment: ok, so basically I want a unicode aware isLower/isUpper functions for VC++. but I could not find any so far.

Comment: @Rahul:  The locale specific versions Billy points out are EXACTLY what you are after.

Comment: yup, got them, they are IsCharUpperW and IsCharLowerW from windows.h