# What should i do when i use std::isupper() with accentuated letter

Tags: c++, if-statement, std

I have to check if the first character of a string is lower case or upper case.

It works good when i use english names like David but when a name with accentuated letter pops up like Á,É,Í,Ó etc.... (like Árpád) then it thinks it is lower case.

```
string name;
std::cin>>name;

if(std::isupper(name[0]))
{
std::cout<<"Upper case"<<std::endl;
}
else
{
std::cout<<"Lower case"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [isupper and islower for wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396050/isupper-and-islower-for-wstring)

Comment: Please don't edit your question after answers are given to you. You can invalidate the answers. I have reverted your edit. If you want to show the solution that worked for you, you can post your own answer. Otherwise, accepting the answer that lead you to the solution is enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the version of [`std::isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper)/[`std::islower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower) you are using work with ASCII letters only (`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` and `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`). To work with other charsets, you need to call [`std::setlocale()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) first, or use the [`std::locale`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) version of [`std::isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isupper)/[`std::islower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/islower), to switch to a charset that supports the characters you are interested in.